# Windows 2008R2 Logon Restrictions and LDAP Authentication

Tags: windows, ldap, authentication

We use a Palo Alto firewall (and its GlobalProtect client) for VPN access to our network.  The firewall uses LDAP to authenticate VPN logins.  I am now trying to setup a user ID for a consultant and I want him to only have access to 1 particular server.  So, on his profile, I set the Logon Workstations to only allow access to the 1 server.  But, with this set, he can't VPN as the authentication fails.  Is there anyway to allow LDAP authentication and access to only 1 machine?

Comment: You can set logon to the server you need then just give your vpn a dns entry and put that in the logon to box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grant the user necessary permissions on the "1 server". They won't be able to login anywhere else because they won't have permission.  This isn't a VPN solution or LDAP solution, instead it is just how permission are granted on the one server.

While this does make them a "Domain User", they'll still only have access to the resources granted which should be limited.

Take for example remote desktop, domain users should be denied access to this resource by default.  Same goes for other resources such as CIFS and websites.  If this isn't the case then its a great opportunity to review how access is granted to resources.

Depending on the level of access they need, Logon restrictions could be used so they can only login during certain times and on specific domain systems.

The alternative is to create local accounts for VPN access and server access.

Comment: In order to be able to VPN in, they need a domain account and all domain accounts are by default allowed to login to all servers.  I'm not sure how I let the user login via VPN and then only give them permission to the 1 server?

Comment: By default, all domain accounts are *not* allowed to login to all servers. If you have deviated from that default, then you've made a design mistake and you should correct that.

Comment: Unfortunately, our security is such that domain users are allowed to login to all servers.  Having read your edited explanation I see what you mean now.  I will use local account for VPN for right now and work on correcting the security.

Comment: FWIW, domain users should never be allowed to login to servers via interactive login (i.e. RDP, Console/Local). Exception being Remote Desktop Servers formerly known as Terminal Servers. It is common to allow domain users to authenticate to servers for checking access to advertised resources such as file shares, websites, etc.